Fetch API Returns Empty Array in Next.js Despite Working API Endpoint
I'm using fetch() to retrieve data from my backend API in a Next.js project, but an empty array ([]) is always returned instead of the expected data. I've verified that the API is working correctly by testing it in a browser or using a tool like Postman. However, when I try to fetch the data in my Next.js component using the following code:
const BookList = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/books");
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  const books = await response.json();
  console.log(books);
}

axios() is working perfectly but i want to use fetch() as it is recommended to use it in Next.js. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it to retrieve the correct data in my Next.js component?

Could you provide the axios call that works in your case?

const BookList = async () => {
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/books")
.then((data) => console.log(data));

Can you give a sample of your response ? Your code works fine for example with this API : https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/books

Yes it is working with this API: https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/books even by using fetch( ). What can be the problem with my API? It's working with axios but not with fetch.

Please provide the response data that you get with axios.

You can try to use await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/books", { cache: 'no-store' });

By using axios i get this response from my API: http://localhost:3001/api/books%22
[
{
_id: '6630ea8d36ab173f809dcf3d',
title: 'Computer',
author: null,
coverImage: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dam93gr7v/image/upload/v1714481803/book-covers/s99u90pyotpjr6gudkzc.jpg',
file: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dam93gr7v/raw/upload/v1714481806/books/xcdv4dpfvt4xbsjzl59c.pdf',
genre: 'Programming',
createdAt: '2024-04-30T12:56:45.768Z',
updatedAt: '2024-04-30T12:56:45.768Z',
__v: 0
}
]

I'll post an answer below, can you upvote and mark it as answer. So other people can see it too and get helped ?

The answer is to force next fetch function to force update on every request.
Because next fetch function is basically caching every request until invalidated. In order to do that you just have to pass { cache: 'no-store' }) on the fetch options:
For example:
await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/books", { cache: 'no-store' });

It will force next to fetch directly to remote resource without looking for any cache.
Here's the official documentation for more details
